# RxJava 2, Flowable.doOnCancel not called when DisposableSubscriber disposed

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a DisposableSubscriber to a Flowable. The Flowable runs for some timeUntilTimeout, but in some situations I need to kill it earlier. Right now I call .dispose() on the DisposableSubscriber but the Flowable continues to emit events. Eventually the Flowable times out and .doOnCancel() is called.

I have the following code:

```
private Disposable mDisposableSubscription = null;

public void start() {
    mDisposableSubscription = getFlowable()
            .timeout(timeUntilTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    dispose();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(T t) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
}

public void stop() {
    // Log "dispose"
    mDisposableSubscription.dispose();
}

private Flowable<T> getFlowable() {
    return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<T>() {
        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<T> emitter) {
            startSomeAsyncProcess();
        }
    }).doOnCancel(new Action() {
        public void run() {
            // Log "do on cancel"
            stopSomeAsyncProcess();
        }
    });
}
```

Calling stop() to dispose of the DisposableSubscriber before the Flowable times out means events emitted by the Flowable are no longer handled, but the Flowable continues emitting events and the async process continues running. I was under the impression that calling .dispose() downstream of the Flowable kills the Flowable by calling .doOnCancel(), but this does not appear to be the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The flowable is getting disposed, but you are not checking it on your `Flowable.create` function, so what happens is that the `startSomeAsyncProcess()` ignores it and keeps going.

To solve the issue, you should check the `emitter.isDisposed()` flag to know if you should stop emitting.

Example:

```
Flowable<T> getFlowable() {
    return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<T>() {

        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<T> emitter) {
            while(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                emitter.onNext(...);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

If that `startSomeAsyncProcess()` function doesn't allow you to check the flag, surely there is some way to cancel it. Then you can attach a cancellable:

```
Flowable<T> getFlowable() {
    return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<T>() {

        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<T> emitter) {
            startSomeAsyncProcess();
            emitter.setCancellable(() -> stopSomeAsyncProcess());
            // I don't remember if it's setCancellable() or setDisposable()
        }

    });
}
```

Update: the methods `setCancellable(...)` and `setDisposable(...)` should behave equally, [they just take different arguments](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4812).

Comment: So calling `Disposable.dispose()` will **not** call `Flowable.doOnCancel()` and there is no way to call `.doOnCancel()` if all I have access to in `stop()` is the `Disposable`? So even if the `Flowable` is being disposed, `doOnCancel()` is not called and `stopSomeAsyncProcess()` is not being called.

Comment: @Exudes it doesn't work like that, if you want the `stopAsyncProcess()` to be called when calling `dispose()`, just put it in `emitter.setCancellable(() -> stopAsyncProcess()`.

Comment: I set a `Cancellable` that would call `stopSomeAsyncProcess()` on `cancel()` but `cancel()` was called immediately, without `dispose()` being called. I used `setDisposable()` instead, but its `dispose()` method still wasn't called when `Disposable.dispose()` was called downstream, it was only called when the `Flowable` timed out much later. So I'm still confused how `Disposable.dispose()` affects the upstream `Flowable`. It still doesn't seem to have an effect

Comment: @Exudes `emitter.setCancellable` and `emitter.setDisposable` are the same. The action you put in the cancellable is called both when you call `dispose` on the subscription and when there is an error. I think the timeout also triggers the cancellable action so that you can free resources. Is it not behaving like this? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: It is not behaving that way. Calling dispose() downstream did not call stopAsyncProcess() when I used emitter.setDisposable(() -> stopAsyncProcess()). Instead, stopAsyncProcess still wasn't called until timeout, just as it was before. Just to clarify, the chain is basically this: getFlowable().subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber()).dispose(), but it does not call my disposable in the emitter

Comment: @Exudes this sounds like a thread problem. Can you make sure the `dispose()` method is actually being called? it is likely that your observer is not actually async (i.e. it is blocking) and the thread that calls `dispose()` is blocked at `subscribeWith` until the timeout releases it. Use `subscribeOn` and `obserbeOn` to fix it.

Comment: I have logs, dispose() is being called when expected. My logs in emitter.setDisposable(){ dispose(); } are not logged until timeout. This code is being migrated to RxJava 2 from 1, so the threading should not be an issue as it was not previously